# How to add custom code to a Text Page type item created in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have recently installed Txt starter kit on Umbraco 7. In content section of admin page, I created a page of type Text Page under Home. For the page I am limited to only selecting a picture and writing a content. On my former ASP.net website, I had the following code getting some input from user and doing a cost approximation:

```
<div class="costSection"  runat="server">            
    برآورد قیمت ترجمه:
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="نوع ترجمه "></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTranslationType" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Value="0">فارسی به انگلیسی</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">انگلیسی به فارسی</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">فرانسه به فارسی</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <br />
    <asp:Label runat="server" Text="تعداد کلمه "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtWordsCount" runat="server"  CssClass="costSection" ></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnCalcCost" CssClass="costSection" OnClick="btnCalcCost_Click" Text="محاسبه هزینه"/>
    <asp:Label Text="" ID="lblCost" runat="server" CssClass="costSection"> </asp:Label>
</div>
```

And the C# code was:

```
protected void btnCalcCost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int userChoice;
    try{int.TryParse(ddlTranslationType.SelectedValue,out userChoice);}
    catch(Exception ex){
        lblCost.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblCost.Text=ex.Message;
        return;
    }
    int wordsCount;
    if (txtWordsCount.Text == null || !int.TryParse(txtWordsCount.Text,out wordsCount))
    {
        lblCost.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblCost.Text = "لطفا تعداد کلمات را وارد کنید";
        return;
    }
    float cost=0;
    switch (userChoice)
    {
        case 0: //Farsi-English
            cost = (float)wordsCount / 250 * 13000;
            break;
        case 1: //English-Farsi
            cost = (float)wordsCount / 300 * 8000;
            break;
        case 2: //French-Farsi
            cost = (float)wordsCount / 250 * 20000;
            break;            

    }
    long estimatedCost = (long)cost;
    lblCost.ForeColor= System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lblCost.Text = estimatedCost.ToString()+" تومان ";
}
```

In my new Umbraco post, I want to have this code, but I don't know where to add the markup and the C# code for it to work.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet :(

Comment: Ah, okay then. Remember me when you do ;-)

Comment: Sure buddy :) if it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at Umbraco macros at https://our.umbraco.org/DOCUMENTATION/reference/templating/macros/ - you can create a partial view and put your code in there, then add the macro to either your template or to individual pages via the editor.